# Is linux shell just optional utility or mandatory when running processes

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm still pretty confused with the role of linux shell running programs despite of using linux a lot.

I understand there are two type of shells, interactive shells and non-interactive shells. Terminal session interacts with interactive shell, and scripts run in non-interactive shell. But is there really other difference than ability to read input and print output? If I invoke script from shell, does it run in this interactive shell or new non-interactive shell inside shell?

Also, when I execute binary either by invoking it through interactive shell or graphical interface, does it always run in the shell, or could a process run without shell at all? It's said that all processes communicates with kernel through the shell, but I'm confused because in docker, you can define the entrypoint to be either a binary or "sh -c binary".

Comment: A shell is a command interpreter. Not more, not less. It is an executable like any other which also means that it is _not_ in the game just because you execute another executable. Some "programs" do indeed use a "wrapper shell script" to setup their environment before some binary or script thingy is executed. But that is up to how that "program" is set up. Typically however there is am initial shell process created for a user that logs in, the so called "login shell". From that process all other users processes are spawned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shell is just one possible interface. Every Linux system has a notion of a "first" process (usually called `init`) that is started directly by the kernel. *Every* other program on your computer is started by another process that first forks itself, then calls `exec` (actually, one of about 6 functions in the same family) to replace itself with a different program.

The shell is just one possible interface, one that parses text into requests to run other programs. The shell command line `mv foo bar` is parsed as a request to pass fork the shell and call `exec` in the new copy with the three words `mv`, `foo`, and `bar` as arguments.

Consider the following snippet of Python:

```
subprocess.call(["mv", "foo", "bar"])
```

which basically does the same thing: the Python program forks itself and calls `exec` with the three given strings as arguments. There is *no* shell involvement.

Comment: Little off topic, but if the process which spawned another process via fork terminates, may the child still continue? In other words, are they independent after the fork? If I spawn process from shell in the foreground and close the shell, process also terminates. But when I run it in the background (&), shell may be closed without spawned process terminating. What's the relation of to forking? Also, super off topic, but where from docker container entrypoint is forked?

Comment: @Tuomas: you might want to ask a separate question - but first, read what you can about [**orphaned processes**](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orphan_process).  In short, the process with ID 1 becomes the parent of the orphaned process.

Comment: Yes, there are systems with a Linux kernel but no shell - for example the [Empeg Car](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empeg_Car) audio player, which by default runs the player binary as its init process.

Answer (score 0):

The shell is just a convenient UI that lets you run other processes the way you want to. It can also run scripts to do the same. That's all it does. It's not responsible for doing anything for the processes once it runs them.

You could entirely replace it with `python`which lets you do the same things, but that's annoying because you have to type chepner's `subprocess.call(["mv", "foo", "bar"])`just to to run the `mv` program. If you wanted to pipe one program to another, you'd need 5-10 such lines. Not much fun to write interactively.

You could entirely replace it with KDE/Gnome/whatever and double click programs to run them, but that's not very flexible since you can't include arguments and such, and you can't automate it.

> I understand there are two type of shells, interactive shells and non-interactive shells. Terminal session interacts with interactive shell, and scripts run in non-interactive shell. But is there really other difference than ability to read input and print output?

It's just two different modes that you can run `sh` with.  You want comfy keyboard shortcuts, aliases and options to help type things manually (interactively), but they're pointless or annoying when running pre-written script.

> If I invoke script from shell, does it run in this interactive shell or new non-interactive shell inside shell?

It runs in a new, independent process. You can run it in the same interactive shell instance with `source yourscript`, which is basically the same as typing the script contents on the keyboard.

> Also, when I execute binary either by invoking it through interactive shell or graphical interface, does it always run in the shell, or could a process run without shell at all?

The process always runs entirely independently of the shell, but may share the same terminal.

> It's said that all processes communicates with kernel through the shell,

Processes never talk to the kernel through the shell. They talk through syscalls.

> but I'm confused because in docker, you can define the entrypoint to be either a binary or "sh -c binary".

For a simple binary, the two are identical.

If you want to e.g. set up pipes or redirections because the process doesn't do it on its own, you can use `sh -c` to have a shell do it instead.